# Error when running python in Wine: fixme:msvcrt:__clean_type_info_names_internal

Tags: python, wine

Anytime I run python in wine I get block of errors that keep popping up. The code still seems to run but the errors make it difficult to see what else is going on.

For example when I run this code `wine c:/Python27/python.exe -m pip install pyinstaller` I get this big block of errors

```
fixme:msvcrt:__clean_type_info_names_internal (0x1e8d8088) stub
fixme:msvcrt:__clean_type_info_names_internal (0x1e7ba8c4) stub
fixme:msvcrt:__clean_type_info_names_internal (0x15df850) stub
fixme:msvcrt:__clean_type_info_names_internal (0xd2eff0) stub
fixme:msvcrt:__clean_type_info_names_internal (0x1d181730) stub
fixme:msvcrt:__clean_type_info_names_internal (0xcfa498) stub
fixme:msvcrt:__clean_type_info_names_internal (0x1d1b5210) stub
fixme:msvcrt:__clean_type_info_names_internal (0x1d114810) stub
fixme:msvcrt:__clean_type_info_names_internal (0x10139568) stub
fixme:msvcrt:__clean_type_info_names_internal (0x42ca30) stub
fixme:msvcrt:__clean_type_info_names_internal (0x1e24e5b8) stub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If messages are bothering you simply suppress them with WINEDEBUG=-msvcrt.